# An infinite group generated by all its order two elements

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group, combinatorial-group-theory, involutions

Let $G$ be an infinite group generated by all its order two elements.

> Is there something interesting that can be said about such $G$?

The group $G$ I had in mind is the group of automorphisms of $k[x,y]$,
$k$ is a field of characteristic zero; if I am not wrong, $G$ equals its subgroup generated by all involutions (the group generated by all involutions is a normal subgroup of $G$, and this fact somehow implies my claim,
hopefully).

Please see [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326892495_Products_of_involutions_of_an_infinite-dimensional_vector_space) very nice paper which implies, in case the group of automorphisms of $k[x,y]$ indeed equals its subgroup generated by all involutions (of $k$-algebras), that every $k$-algebra automorphism of $k[x,y]$ is a product of at most four involutions
(since a $k$-algebra involution is in particular a $k$-vector space involution; just forget the multiplication in $k[x,y]$).

Thank you very much!

Comment: You write "...the group $G$ I had in mind..." So, are you asking about that particular group? Or are you asking the question in the yellow box which appears to be about a more general class of groups?

Comment: @LeeMosher, good question, thanks. I have mentioned the group of automorphisms of $k[x,y]$ to show where my question came from. I am familiar with some general results concerning that group (generation by affine and triangular automorphisms; free amalgamated structure). I wonder if something can be said in general, and then apply it to that group I had in mind.

Comment: I don't think your statement about just forgetting the multiplication is correct if you want to conclude that the $k$-algebra involutions generate a $k$-algebra automorphism group. (I have only skimmed the paper you cite. Perhaps it includes some results specific to $k$-algebras that I did notice.)

Comment: @RobArthan, I have not presented the argument why the group of $k$-algebra automorphisms of $k[x,y]$ is generated by all involutions on $k[x,y]$. Truly, this claim is essentialy not mine; I have once seen that claim for the group of $k$-algebra automorphisms of the first Weyl algebra over $k$ and it seemed to me that the same argument also works for $k[x,y]$.

Comment: So what is the significance of the sentence in parentheses beginning "since" in your question?

Comment: I meant the following: (1) Replacing $A_1(k)$ by $k[x,y]$ to obtain that the group of $k$-algebra automorphisms of $k[x,y]$ is generated by $k$-algebra involutions of $k[x,y]$. So if $g$ is an arbitrary automorphism of $k[x,y]$, then $g=\iota_1 \cdots \iota_n$, where $\iota_j$ is a $k$-algebra involution and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. (2) Moreover, by https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.02224v1.pdf (if I understood it correctly), we must have $n \leq 4$, since a $k$-algebra involution is in particular a $k$-vector space involution. (But perhaps I am missing something).

Comment: Maybe that paper just says that an automorphism $g$ of infinite dimensional vector space can be written as a product of at most four $k$-vector space involutions, but maybe there are several different ways to write $g$ (not trivial ones= adding $\iota \iota$ to a given product), so my conclusion (2) is wrong.

Comment: That's right, the paper is giving a lower bound on the number of involutions required to represent an arbitrary automorphism, not an upper bound.

Comment: One thing you can say of such a group is that its abelianization is a 2-elementary abelian group.

Comment: I don't see the relation between the linked paper by Seguins-Pazzis, which deals with the group of automorphisms of an infinite-dimensional vector space over an arbitrary field, and the group of automorphisms of $k[x,y]$ (I expect, as $k$-algebra, which should be said explicitly).

Comment: @RobArthan, thank you for the clarification (yes, I understand my error).

Comment: @YCor, please, could you slightly elaborate your first comment, maybe in an answer?

Comment: There are lots of finitely-generated, non-abelian examples. In particular, "being generated by order two elements" is closed in free products so, for example, $D_{\infty}=C_2\ast C_2$ works, as does $Q_8\ast Q_8$ (where by $Q_8$ I mean the quaternion group of order $8$), $S_n\ast Q_8$, and so on.

Comment: @user1729, thank you for your comment. What if $G$ is not finitely generated, like in the case of $k$-algebra automorphisms of $k[x,y]$? (there is a result that this group is a free amalgamated product of the affine automorphisms and the triangular automorphisms).

Comment: @user237522 I'm not sure I understand your question. I mean, "being generated by order two elements" is closed under free products, whether you assume finite generation or not. There are lots of "wild" group which are generated by their elements of order two. For example, the "finitary" symmetric group on any set is generated by its transpositions (that is, the group is bijections $X\rightarrow X$ which move only finitely many elements).

Comment: @user1729, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Other examples of "wild" groups are the Brin-Thompson groups $nV$ (see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.04409.pdf)), and probably other "Thompson-like" groups.

Comment: @user1729, thank you for the additional examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you can say of a group $G$ generated by its elements of order 2 is that its abelianization $G_{\mathrm{ab}}=G/[G,G]$ is a 2-elementary abelian group. Indeed, $G_{\mathrm{ab}}$, being a quotient of $G$ is also generated by elements of order 2, and for an abelian group, this means being 2-elementary abelian (which in turn is equivalent to being isomorphic to a vector space over $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Indeed, any quotient of $G$ must also be generated by elements of order 2.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_abelian_group